# Django test failing due to AssertionError:201 !=400

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-tests

Got the following view

```
class MyUserCreate(APIView):
    '''
    Creates the user. 
    '''
    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = MyUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And wanted to create a test to ensure I'm not able to create a user with the same username.

In serializers.py, the username in MyUserSerializer loks like this

```
username = serializers.CharField(
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())],
        max_length=32
        )
```

and in models.py, the username in MyUser

```
username = models.CharField(db_column='username', unique=True, max_length=20)
```

In tests.py

```
class MyUserTest(APITestCase):

    ...

    def test_create_user_with_preexisting_username(self):
        data = {
                'username': 'testing',
                'password': 'test'
                }

        response = self.client.post(self.create_url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        self.assertEqual(MyUser.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data['username']), 1)
```

Up to this point the tests for user creation, user without username, user with a too long username, ... all worked out fine. The problem only happens in this specific test.

The user testing exists in the DB

[image: Users in the DB]

If I run

```
python manage.py tests
```

then

```
FAIL: test_create_user_with_preexisting_username (codeLabsApp.tests.MyUserTest)
Ensure we can't create a user with preexisting username.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AssertionError: 201 != 400
```

So I'm getting a 201 Created instead of a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: When you say "The user testing exists in the DB" do you mean that the data is present in the TEST database, or the database your project is using normally? The test database should be empty between tests, unless you're setting up fixtures elsewhere. I believe a 201 is expected here. If you `self.client.post()` a second time- you should get the expected 400. You have a condition asserting that there is only a single user as well `self.assertEqual(MyUser.objects.count(), 1)`

Comment: @rob so at your sight the problem is in how the test is designed - it should include two `self.client.post()`. It might make sense considering the other thing you also mention, «The test database should be empty between tests» (wonder where you extracted that practise from?). Anyways, in this case the database was indeed empty until I created one superuser name "testing" and then ran the test to see if it allowed me to create a user with that same name. And it did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database), there is no your local database usage due test running.
So, I guess, user in the database table screenshot exists in your local database.
When you running your tests, Django creates another database (only for current tests). In that database you have no user `testing` except of that user was created in `setUp` test-class method, or in fixture.
The most simple way to fix it is to change test method:

```
def test_create_user_with_preexisting_username(self):
    existed_username = "testing"
    existed_user = MyUser.objects.create(username=existed_username)
    data = {
            'username': existed_username,
            'password': 'test'
            }

    response = self.client.post(self.create_url, data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    self.assertEqual(MyUser.objects.count(), 2)
    self.assertEqual(len(response.data['username']), 1)
```

Also, be careful when you get length of `response.data`. If you have paginated response somewhere you will not receive all expected instances (maximum by page size).

Comment: That way I get `AssertionError: 2 != 1` due to this line: `self.assertEqual(MyUser.objects.count(), 1)`

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 do you create user before? in fixtures or in `setUp` method?

Comment: Correct. I create in tests.py one with setUp method. So, will edit the number in that line to 2.